# How do you set the response status code in Polka.js framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapper, polka

Seems like it should be simple.

Trying:

```
res.status(500).send({ error: "That type already exists." })
```

Gets me:

> TypeError: res.status is not a function

This is in sapper, not sure if that makes a diff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done:

```
res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/lukeed/polka), you use `res.statusCode = 500`, or if you're throwing an error in a middleware, you'd use `err.code = 500`.